# How to create a view that would change the interface?

Tags: android, xml

Currently, I am making a contacts application. There is a feature that I would like to add in.

[image]

As you can see, there are 3 buttons at the bottom of the screen: Contacts, Phone, Groups. By clicking any one of these three buttons, I would be directed to another screen. This is the feature that I would like to add. How to make it? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can start a new activity . and if you want to stay in the same activity you can use `setContentView(layout)` to set new layout for a screen.

Comment: Can you give me more details about it? I am just a beginner in android apps development. Or links that teach about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: ok...tell me whether you want to move to next activity or you want to stay on the same.

Comment: I want the move to the next activity.

Comment: Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(activity.this, YourNewClass.class);
startActivity(goToNextActivity);